# Instances of Angels by name in Shas

Tags: talmud-gemara, malach-angel

I am curious about a list (does not need to be  exhaustive) of various places where Angels are mentioned by name in Shas/Talmud.

I am so far aware of two: the angels listed by name that visited Avraham and Gavriel mentioned by name on Yoma 77 discussing Daniel. I am curious as to other places where Angels are referred to by name. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hi @Michael this is quite a wide-reaching question.

The following is not definitive but hopefully a good start. People can feel free to turn this answer into a Wiki and add to it.

---

**GROUP**

[Bava Metziah 86b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.86b.20?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) - lists Michael, Gavriel, and Raphael who visted Avraham

[Yoma 37a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.37a.10?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) - Also reference to three above

[Berachos 4b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.4b.26?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) - Hierarchy of angels based on flight incl. Michael, Gavriel, Eliyahu and Malach Hamaveis

[Berachos 4b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.4b.23?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) - Comparing Michael and Gavriel

---

**GAVRIEL**

[Megilla 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.12b.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - Gavriel fashioning a tail for Vashti

[Sanhedrin 21b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.21b.15?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) - Gavriel's action following Shlomo marrying Pharoah's daughter

[Sotah 33b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.33a.9?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) - Gavriel teaching Yosef 70 languages

[Pesachim 118b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.118b.14?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Punctuated_Aramaic&lang=bi) - Hashem speaking to Gavriel

[Menachos 29a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.29a.14?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) - Gavriel's belt

[Sanhedrin 95b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.95b.10?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) - Hashem speaking to Gavriel about his scythe

---

**MICHAEL**

[Zevachim 62a](https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.62a.5?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Menachos 110a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.110a.9?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) & [Chagigah 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12b.6?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) - Michael offering sacrifices on altar in shamayim

[Avoda Zara 42b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.62a.5?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - lists Michael as part of list of things that one slaughters an animal for in order to worship which is forbidden to do

[Yoma 77a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.77a.2?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) - Conversation between Hashem and Michael

---

**MALACH HAMAVEIS (MH)**

[Shabbos 30b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.30b.1?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) - MH killing David Hamelech

[Bava Basra 16a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.16a.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) - Satan and MH being one

[Shabbos 89a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.89a.2?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) - Talks about how all the angels came to admire Moshe for arguing why humans should receive the Torah and even the MH gave something

[Avoda Zara 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.5a.15?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) - The Jewish people accepted the Torah only in order that the Angel of Death would not rule over them

[Avoda Zara 20b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.20b.7?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) - first talks about not to look at animals mating and how even if one were like the MH who is full of eyes, a person shouldn't look and then later, the way the MH kills humans

[Yoma 77b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.77b.16?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) - MH doesn't have permission to pass through river that will in future flow from the Holy of Holies

[Bava Metziah 36b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.36b.7?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) - The reason that a person liable to pay is because even if the Angel of Death spared the life of the animal, it would be standing in the house of the thief due to the negligence of the bailee.

[Avoda Zara 35b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.35b.8?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) - MH love for talmud chacham

[Chullin 35b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.35b.11?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) -  It was necessary for Rabbi Shimon to teach the halacha of blood of the animal that is dead as a result of natural causes, as it could enter your mind to say: What difference is there to me if one killed the animal himself, and what difference is there to me if the animal was killed by the angel of death?

[Bava Kamma 60b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.60b.9?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) - If there is a plague in the city, a person should not enter the shul alone, as the Angel of Death leaves his utensils there

---

Answer (score 2):

A list of angels that appear in the Talmud, Midrash and Zohar (AKA Chazalic literature) was compiled by [Rabbi Reuven Margolies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuvein_Margolies) in his book Mal'achei Elyon, which can be viewed (with payement) on Otzar Hachochma (you can see some sample pages [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=155246&pagenum=3)) or bought (for example, [here](https://mosadharavkook.com/shop/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%99-%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F/)). He names 325 angels, all sourced.

Comment: Dude it must be 2.30am by you right now! That's dedication! :-)

Comment: @Dov haha :) having trouble falling asleep, so I might as well look into interesting Torah subjects...

Comment: Kol hakavod! Layla tov!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one  - Sanhedrin 38B

> אמר רב נחמן האי מאן דידע לאהדורי למינים כרב אידית ליהדר ואי לא לא ליהדר אמר ההוא מינא לרב אידית כתיב (שמות כד, א) ואל משה אמר עלה אל ה' עלה אלי מיבעי ליה א"ל זהו מטטרון ששמו כשם רבו דכתיב (שמות כג, כא) כי שמי בקרבו אי הכי ניפלחו ליה כתיב (שמות כג, כא) אל תמר בו אל תמירני בו אם כן לא ישא לפשעכם למה לי א"ל הימנותא בידן דאפילו בפרוונקא נמי לא קבילניה דכתיב (שמות לג, טו) ויאמר אליו אם אין פניך הולכים וגו'

> Rav Naḥman says: This one, i.e., any person, who knows how to respond to the heretics as effectively as Rav Idit should respond to them, but if he does not know, he should not respond to them. The Gemara relates: A certain heretic said to Rav Idit: It is written in the verse concerning God: “And to Moses He said: Come up to the Lord” (Exodus 24:1). The heretic raised a question: It should have stated: Come up to Me. Rav Idit said to him: This term, “the Lord,” in that verse is referring to the angel Metatron, whose name is like the name of his Master, as it is written: “Behold I send an angel before you to keep you in the way and to bring you to the place that I have prepared. Take heed of him and obey his voice; do not defy him; for he will not pardon your transgression, for My name is in him” (Exodus 23:20–21).